# Execute functions of another C# running program

Tags: c#

I have a litle program in c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int count;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(func_count());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static int func_count()
        {
            return count++;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write another simple C# program that will be able JUST to execute the func_count(). The first exe will be allready running, I don't want to execute it inside the second application and reflect it's properties.
In C after getting the right to access the memory region to avoid seg fault I would have to use a pointer to a function - something like:

```
int (* func_ptr)(); //pointer to function

func_ptr = func_count_address
```

What's a simple way to do this in C# like above?
Suppose that the first program (the one given) is as is and I can't change the code.

Thank you

Comment: So you want to expose the `func_count` as a "service" so that other program(s) can use it? Or you want to be able to access any C# running program and execute any of its methods?

Comment: may be you are thinking of .dll ; May be

Comment: The second, to access the C# program and execute any of its methods

Comment: @marmotas It's very very difficult. In Windows (as in all the modern OS), it's very difficult for a process to attach to another process and execute some random code of that process.

Comment: Yes I'm also thinking of dll but first I want to learn how to do that in a simple running program. I want also to learn how to access some of it's objects but I decided to start with this program's function.

Comment: You have two problems: A) You need to "attach" your process to another process and B) You have to find a "private" method of the attached process. For the A) part you can begin reading http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces

Comment: @xanatos for the B) I have searched a lot in the internet and I was disappointed finding out that C# pointers are only for "unmanaged types" http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajeshvs/PointersInCSharp11112005051624AM/PointersInCSharp.aspx

Comment: @marmotas That isn't a real problem. `IntPtr` is equivalent to `void*`

Comment: @xanatos I use the corresponding pointer to function in C#:
public delegate int function_pointer(int x, int y);
function_pointer func_ptr;
And the a statement like func_ptr = 0x1230918 is not allowed - in order to set the func_ptr to refer to location of the func_count. I can't even use the statement &func_count inside the first program.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply call the static method: `ConsoleApplication1.Program.func_count()`. This of course assumes that you reference the assembly where `ConsoleApplication` is located within your second app and that the method you want to invoke is public (which is currently is NOT).

EDIT: If you may not change the access-modifier of the desired method you may use reflection to invoke it however. 
Sth. like this:

```
MethodInfo m = typeof(ConsoleApplication.Program).GetMethod("func_count", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
object result = m.Invoke(null, yourParams);
```

Usually you´d need an instance on which that method is executed. Since your method is `static` it does not need it and therefor the first param to `Invoke` is `NULL`.

Comment: If is a private method and I can't change that, is there a way to access it? Reflection means that I will have to execute the the first process inside the second, which I don't want to, right?

Comment: No, it simply means "access any member of a class within a given assembly". But you have to ensure that the assembly that contains App1 is loaded (not neccessarily executing). You can achieve this by adding the assembly as reference to your second one (where your App2 is located).

Comment: Ok, thank you for making this clear to me. Do you mean including in my code a statement like "using ConsoleApplication1;"? What I want to learn from this question is how to access a method or an instance of an object from another running exe.

Comment: Executing that method isn´t that difficult. The question is: do you need the state of the used variables within this method (that means do you need the number from `count`from that application or does your second one may have its own counter)?

Comment: Yes I need the state of the used variables. So I want to able to increase the value of the count variable of the first program while it is waiting from me to press a key.